# E-visa for 20hr layover at Istanbul airport, is hotel reservation necessary?

Tags: transit, hotels, istanbul, turkish-airlines

I am travelling from Germany to Pakistan. I have a 20hr layover at Istanbul airport. So, I want to take advantage of the free Istanbul tour provided by Turkish Airlines as I'm travelling with Turkish Airlines in a roud-trip. I need an E-visa to step out from the airport. I fulfill all the requirements for this visa except the hotel reservation thing. I am not planning to reserve the hotel. Just thinking of spending the night at the airport, next day the tour and then straight flight to pakistan.

Am I still eligible for to get the e-visa without the hotel reservation?

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody seems to know about that one :-( Not sure if it matters here but adding information about your citizenship often helps for visa questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to be on the safe side, you can always book a cheap hostel even if you don't plan to stay in it. With 12% booking fee and a booking protection it would effectively cost you 1-3 euros which you can cancel and even redeem on a later booking. Compared to 15 Euros (depending from where you are) visa it is hardly a big extra cost.

I believe a visa shouldn't be a problem without a previously made booking, since i do remember I haven't been asked to show my booking confirmation last time I was there, but still it is not something i would bet on to be the case every time.

It would be great if you could post back your experience if you tried getting an on site visa without booking previously.